# How to hack this Bokeh HexTile plot to fix the coords, label placement and axes?

Tags: python, plot, coordinates, bokeh, hexagonal-tiles

Below is Bokeh 1.4.0 code that tries to **draw a HexTile map of the input dataframe, with axes, and tries to place labels on each hex**.
I've been stuck on this for two days solid, reading bokeh doc, examples and github known issues, SO, [Bokeh Discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org/) and [Red Blob Games's superb tutorial on Hexagonal Grids](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/), and trying code. (I'm less interested in raising Bokeh issues for the future, and far more interested in pragmatic workarounds to known limitations to just get my map code working today.) Plot is below, and code at bottom.

Here are the issues, in rough decreasing order of importance (it's impossible to separate the root-cause and tell which causes which, due to the way Bokeh handles glyphs. If I apply one scale factor or coord transform it fixes one set of issues, but breaks another, 'whack-a-mole' effect):

1. The **label placement** is obviously wrong, but I can't seem to hack up any variant of either (x,y) coords or (q,r) coords to work. (I tried combinations of `figure(..., match_aspect=True))`, I tried `1/sqrt(2)` scaling the (x,y)-coords, I tried `Hextile(... size, scale)` params as per redblobgames, e.g. `size =  1/sqrt(3)` ~ 0.57735).
2. Bokeh forces the **origin to be top left, and y-coords to increase as you go down, however the default axis labels show y or r as being negative**. I found I still had to use `p.text(q, -r, ...`. I suppose I have to manually patch the auto-supplied yaxis labels or TickFormatter to be positive.
3. I use `np.mgrid` to generate the coord grid, but I still **seem to have to assign q-coords right-to-left**: `np.mgrid[0:8, (4+1):0:-1]`. Still no matter what I do, **the hexes are flipped L-to-R**

   - (Note: empty '' counties are placeholders to get the desired shape, hence the boolean mask `[counties!='']` on grid coords. This works fine and I want to leave it as-is)
4. The source (q,r) coords for the hexes are integers, and I use 'odd-r' offset coords (not axial or hexagonal coords). **No matter what `HexTile(..., size, scale)` args I use, one or both dimensions in the plot is wrong or squashed**. Or whether I include the `1/sqrt(2)` factor in coord transform.

   - My +q-axis is east and my +r-axis should be 120° SSE
5. Ideally I'd like to have my origin at bottom-left (math plot style, not computer graphics). But Bokeh apparently doesn't support that, I can live without that. However defaulting the y-axis labels to negative, while requiring a mix of positive and negative coords, is confusing. Anyway, how to hack an automatic fix to that with minimum grief? (manual `p.yrange = Range1d(?, ?)`?)
6. Bokeh's approach to attaching (hex) glyphs to plots is a hard idiom to use. Ideally I simply **want to reference (q,r)-coords everywhere for hexes, labels, axes. I never want to see (x,y)-coords** appearing on axes, label coords, tick-marks, etc. but seems Bokeh won't allow you. I guess you have to manually hack the axes and ticks later. Also, the plot<->glyph interface doesn't allow you to expose a (q,r) <-> (x,y) coord transform function, certainly not a bidirectional one.
7. The default axes don't seem to have any accessors to automatically find their current extent/limits; `p.yaxis.start`/`end` are empty unless you specified them. The result from `p.yaxis.major_tick_in`,`p.yaxis.major_tick_out` is also wrong, for this plot it gives (2,6) for both x and y, seems to be clipping those to the interior multiples of 2(?). **How to automatically get the axes' extent?**

My current plot:

[image: Bad HexTile plot]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt    
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glyphs import HexTile
from bokeh.io import show

# Data source is a list of county abbreviations, in (q,r) coords...
counties = np.array([
    ['TE','DY','AM','DN', ''],
    ['DL','FM','MN','AH', ''],
    ['SO','LM','CN','LH', ''],
    ['MO','RN','LD','WH','MH'],
    ['GA','OY','KE','D',  ''],
    ['',  'CE','LS','WW', ''],
    ['LC','TA','KK','CW', ''],
    ['KY','CR','WF','WX', ''],
    ])
#counties = counties[::-1] # UNUSED: flip so origin is at bottom-left

# (q,r) Coordinate system is “odd/even-r” horizontal Offset coords
r, q = np.mgrid[0:8, (4+1):0:-1]
q = q[counties!='']
r = r[counties!='']

sqrt3 = sqrt(3)
# Try to transform odd-r (q,r) offset coords -> (x,y). Per Red Blob Games' tutorial.
x = q - (r//2) # this may be slightly dubious
y = r

counties_df = pd.DataFrame({'q': q, 'r': r, 'abbrev': counties[counties!=''], 'x': x, 'y': y })
counties_ds = ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(counties_df)) # ({'q': q, 'r': r, 'abbrev': counties[counties != '']})

p = figure(tools='save,crosshair') # match_aspect=True?

glyph = HexTile(orientation='pointytop', q='x', r='y', size=0.76, fill_color='#f6f699', line_color='black') # q,r,size,scale=??!?!!? size=0.76 is an empirical hack.
p.add_glyph(counties_ds, glyph)

p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None

print(f'Axes: x={p.xaxis.major_tick_in}:{p.xaxis.major_tick_out} y={p.yaxis.major_tick_in}:{p.yaxis.major_tick_out}')

# Now can't manage to get the right coords for text labels
p.text(q, -r, text=["(%d, %d)" % (q,r) for (q, r) in zip(q, r)], text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")
# Ideally I ultimately want to fix this and plot `abbrev` column as the text label

show(p)
```

Comment: I've answered below, because I care about making sure Bokeh users have information. But this is a bad question by SO standards (it's not one focused question, in particular) and it would not surprise me if people vote to close it over time. This kind of question is much more suited to the Project Discourse: https://discourse.bokeh.org/ where we are happy to have more open-ended and collaborative discussions.

Comment: @bigreddot: Appreciate your detailed answer, but it's an extremely good question by SO standards, and I've been using SO for 10 years. I spent all of yesterday unsuccessfully using both [`axial_to_cartesian`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh.util.hex.axial_to_cartesian) and `cartesian_to_axial`, and the bottom line is if you don't get both `size` and `scale` parameters right , the coords will be off and give gross rounding error. If you can't set up the coord system, everything else breaks, as I describe, and prove in code. That's not a 'lack of focus'.

Comment: That's not a 'lack of focus' in the question, it's that the doc is genuinely cryptic... Odd/even-r offset coords are going to be the most common coords for people coming from dataframes (as opposed to video games). Anyway thanks for the tips, I'll try to post the solution by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my solution and plot. Mainly per @bigreddot's advice, but there's still some coordinate hacking needed:

1. Expecting users to pass input coords as axial instead of offset coords is a major limitation. I work around this. There's no point in creating a `offset_to_cartesian()` because we need to negate r in two out of three places:
2. My input is even-r offset coords. I still need to manually apply the offset: `q = q + (r+1)//2`
3. I need to manually negate r in both the `axial_to_cartesian()` call and the datasource creation for the glyph. (But not in the `text()` call).
4. The call needs to be: `axial_to_cartesian(q, -r, size=2/3, orientation='pointytop')`
5. Need `p = figure(match_aspect=True ...)` to prevent squishing
6. I need to manually create my x,y axes to get the range right

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.models.glyphs import HexTile
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.util.hex import cartesian_to_axial, axial_to_cartesian

counties = np.array([
    ['DL','DY','AM','',    ''],
    ['FM','TE','AH','DN',  ''],
    ['SO','LM','CN','MN',  ''],
    ['MO','RN','LD','MH','LH'],
    ['GA','OY','WH','D' ,''  ],
    [''  ,'CE','LS','KE','WW'],
    ['LC','TA','KK','CW',''  ],
    ['KY','CR','WF','WX',''  ]
    ])

counties = np.flip(counties, (0)) # Flip UD for bokeh

# (q,r) Coordinate system is “odd/even-r” horizontal Offset coords
r, q = np.mgrid[0:8, 0:(4+1)]
q = q[counties!='']
r = r[counties!='']

# Transform for odd-r offset coords; +r-axis goes up
q = q + (r+1)//2
#r = -r # cannot globally negate 'r', see comments

# Transform odd-r offset coords (q,r) -> (x,y)
x, y = axial_to_cartesian(q, -r, size=2/3, orientation='pointytop')

counties_df = pd.DataFrame({'q': q, 'r': -r, 'abbrev': counties[counties!=''], 'x': x, 'y': y })
counties_ds = ColumnDataSource(ColumnDataSource.from_df(counties_df)) # ({'q': q, 'r': r, 'abbrev': counties[counties != '']})

p = figure(match_aspect=True, tools='save,crosshair')

glyph = HexTile(orientation='pointytop', q='q', r='r', size=2/3, fill_color='#f6f699', line_color='black') # q,r,size,scale=??!?!!?
p.add_glyph(counties_ds, glyph)

p.x_range = Range1d(-2,6)
p.y_range = Range1d(-1,8)
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None

p.text(x, y, text=["(%d, %d)" % (q,r) for (q, r) in zip(q, r)],
    text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")

show(p)
```

[image: Corrected plot]

Answer (score 3):

1. There is an [`axial_to_cartesian`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh.util.hex.axial_to_cartesian) function that will just compute the hex centers for you. You can then attach the labels in a variety of orientations and anchoring from these.
2. Bokeh does not force the origin to be anywhere. There is one axial to cartesian mapping Bokeh uses, exactly what is given by [`axial_to_cartesian`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh.util.hex.axial_to_cartesian). The position of the Hex tiles (and hence the cartesian coordinates that the axes display) follows from this. If you want different ticks, Bokeh affords lots of control points over both tick location and tick labelling.
3. There is more than one convention for Axial coords. Bokeh picked the one that has the r-axis tile "up an to the left", i.e. the one explicitly shown here:

   https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#hex-tiles
4. Bokeh expects up-and-to-the-left axial coords. You will need to convert whatever coordinate system you have to that. For "squishing" you will need to set `match_aspect=True` to ensure the "data space" aspect ratio matches the "pixel space" aspect ratio 1-1.

   Alternatively, if you don't or can't use auto-ranging you will need to set the plot size carefully and also control the border sizes with `min_border_left` etc to make sure the borders are always big enough to accommodate any tick labels you have (so that the inner region will not be resized)
5. I don't really understand this question, but you have absolute control over what ticks visually appear, regardless of the underlying tick data. Besides the built-in formatters, there is [`FuncTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#functickformatter) that lets you format ticks any way you want with a snippet of JS code. *[1]* (And you also have control of where ticks are located, if you want that.)

   *[1] Please note the CoffeeScript and `from_py_func` options are both deprecated and being removed in then next 2.0 release.*
6. Again, you'll want to use [`axial_to_cartesian`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh.util.hex.axial_to_cartesian) to position anything other then Hex tiles. No other glyphs in Bokeh understand axial coordinates (which is why we provide the conversion function).
7. You misunderstood what `major_tick_in` and `major_tick_out` are for. They are literally how far the ticks *visually* extend inside and outside the plot frame, *in pixels*.

   Auto-ranging (with `DataRange1d`) is only computed *in the browser, in JavaScript*, which is why the start/end are not available on the "Python" side. If you need to *know* the start/end, you will need to explicitly *set* the start/end, yourself. Note, however that `match_aspect=True` only function with `DataRange1d`. If you explicitly set start/end manually, Bokeh will assume you know what you want, and will honor what you ask for, regardless of what it does to aspect.

Comment: 1,3,4,6:  I spent all of yesterday unsuccessfully using both [`axial_to_cartesian`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/util.html#bokeh.util.hex.axial_to_cartesian) and `cartesian_to_axial`, and the bottom line is if you choose incompatible +q,+r-directions **and** don't get both `size` and `scale` parameters right, the coords will be off and give gross rounding error, which breaks everything else. Once I get this working I will submit some documentation fixes. This is a real useability issue!

Comment: 7. I didn't misunderstand, I know what ticks are, I said "**none** of the (20+) attributes of axes actually tell you their extent", not `p.yaxis.start`/`end` or `.bounds`. So what's the right accessor please? Or there isn't any available from the Python side? In R and Matplotlib this would simply be `ylim`. If no accessor exists, the doc should say so (don't rely on github issues to describe known limitations). Again the documentation is unclear, I'll try to come up with a doc suggestion after I get this working.

Comment: I told you above: *when auto-ranging is active, **the bounds are computed in the browser, in JavaScript***. That means the Python process *never sees the computed values* of start/end. Almost all of the actual work of Bokeh is done *in the browser*. If you want something that renders static images purely in python code, so that you have access to everything "up front", then you might be looking for Matplotlib.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that (a docbug), and it needs to clearly say "this package has no equivalent of `xlim`/`ylim`, when auto-ranging is turned on/ the bounds are computed in the browser". And the workaround is "manually set your own bounds, and remember them" (which still sounds like a missing accessor to me). I need Bokeh not Matplotlib, the HexTile glyph is really neat, we just need to improve the documentation about axial coords for people coming from offset coord-land, like all data scientists starting with dataframes.

Comment: Your documentation contributions will be appreciated by me and many others.

Comment: Totally. Will do. Hey is there any list of other things that are not accessible in Python in Bokeh, since they're done by the browser, in JS? but would be in other frameworks?

Comment: It's worth noting that a *Bokeh Server Application* has some ability to know these computed values, because a Bokeh server is precisely a Python process that keeps these properties "in sync" between JS and Python. That said there is a known issue with *initial* values: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4371

Comment: It's hard to answer that without a discusson. E.g. is the mapping between categorical and synthetic cartesian coordinates something that falls under that? Again, I would suggest the Discourse to discuss this as SO is already prodding to "move to chat" However, I don't use SO chat, at all. I am over-subscribed, monitoring too many places, as it is, and won't add yet another.

Comment: See my solution I posted with comments. I will gladly submit documentation after we figure out why `r` only needs to be negated in two out of three calls... this prevents me writing a nice clean `offset_to_cartesian()` function.